# Convert LinguaPlone sub-language back to language for all content?

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I would like to convert all my content from the sub-language en-ca back to en. What is the API for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call `setLanguage` on your content item. A quick-n-dirty script to accomplish this would be something along the lines of:

```
cat = context.portal_catalog
for brain in cat.unrestrictedSearchResults(Language='en-ca'):
    content = brain.getObject()
    content.setLanguage('en')
    content.reindexObject(idxs=['Language'])
```

You'll need to reindex your content after changing the language setting, but the `idxs` parameter to the `reindexObject` call ensures that only the Language index get's updated, making the process faster.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed the rather obvious reindexObject.